# Phone Number Creation Function

Tags: python, random

I want to add the numbers I created with the create phone_number function to the phone_number list. There must be a total of 10,000,000 phone numbers in the list. I didn't find how to solve it.

I create our random number list in 532-eee-ssss format.
I put 0 in front of random numbers with .zfill().
It will add 'n' phone numbers to the function.

```py
import random

phone_number_list = []

def create_phone_number():
    first = str(532)
    second = str(random.randint(1, 1000)).zfill(3)
    last = (str(random.randint(1, 10000)).zfill(4))
    return list('{}-{}-{}'.format(first, second, last))

for i in range(0, 10000000):
    print(create_phone_number())
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have an indentation error (every line after the `import` statement has too much whitespace in front of it). Other than that your code appears to be working as expected.

Comment: Not sure why you're using `list()` around your return string in `create_phone_number()`. But how doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: if you want to list ALL possibilities, you don't use random, use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

So, If you want to add the phone numbers to the list all you have to do is in the loop do the following:

```
for i in range(0, 10000000):
  phone_number_list.append(create_phone_number())
```

This way your `phone_number_list` will look something like this:

`[['5', '3', '2', '-', '9', '6', '1', '-', '6', '4', '2', '5'], ['5', '3', '2', '-', '5', '5', '4', '-', '0', '9', '8', '3']]`

So if you want to you can store the values in a different way, that may be more readable, by not creating a list for each phone number, but just a string. You can do that just by deleting the transformation to a list.

```
return ('{}-{}-{}'.format(first, second, last))
```

This way the `phone_number_list` looks like this:

```
['532-778-6874', '532-608-0195', '532-971-4515', '532-025-5556', '532-076-4594']
```

I wish this helped:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to do something like:

```
def format_as_phone_number(n: int) -> str:
  return '532-{:03}-{:04}'.format(*divmod(n, 10000))

# loop over every valid number and convert them to phone numbers
every_phone_number = list(map(format_as_phone_number, range(10_000_000))
```

note that the [Faker package](https://faker.readthedocs.io/) can be useful if you want to generate random [phone numbers](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.phone_number.html) in other formats, but isn't so great here as you want to enumerate every number from some specific format